# XML Digital signature verification

Tags: xml, cryptography, rsa

How can the SignedXml be used to verify an xml digital signature of a file (non xml) with SHA256 encryption?
In my case I got the public RSA key modulus and exponent.

I tried to use it, but I cannot load the key to be used probably. I also tried bouncycastle but my verification always fails with no errors, there are not much examples to try.

I do not have much experience with this kind of stuff...

Comment: Please show us what you tried, Angelos. In this form it is off-topic...

Comment: Sorry this was not a constructive question. This was for a .NET implementation. My problems were our sha256 support for System.Security.Cryptography.SignatureDescription, which is available but only for .NET 4.5. 

I managed to resolve my issues for .NET 4.0 by implementing in my code this class [http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/378DF859/2EED7979](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/378DF859/2EED7979)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issues for .NET 4.0 by implementing in my code this class http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/378DF859/2EED7979